# how to livestream webcam server in c++?

Tags: c++, webcam

I am working on a personal project, i want to learn how to create a livestream webcam server. I was trying to upload files and POST them to my server, but the lag results to be too large to be livestream. does anyone have some source code examples for a c++ webcam server? or any pointers that would be helpful?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol), as suggested by its name, should suit better for real-life streaming applications. To reduce the lag you can play with bitrate and dropping frames. There is proprietary pvServer though, which is capable of HTTP-streaming.

Comment: do you have any source code you can share with the community?

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have anything handy.. The wikipage lists some servers. Probably some are open-source. The topic in question is rather wide. So, this is indeed only half of an aswer. Please edit it or post your own if you do